# How can i extends sessionHandler on my class and use read, write,... in my class?

Tags: php, oop, session, cookies, extends

Iam trying to use **sessionHandle**r to write and read session so i can use **openssl_encrypt()** and **openssl_decrypt()** but when i use in my class public session **read()** it shows me in vs red line under the method and if i use any method that exists in **sessionHandler** class it shows my that there're somthing wrong .. so how can i **extends sessionHandler** clase and use its methods ?

```
class SessionManager extends SessionHandler
{
    private $sessionName = 'MYAPPSESSION';
    private $sessionMaxLifetime = 0;        
    private $sessionSSL = false;
    private $sessionHTTPOnly = true;        
    private $sessionPath = "/";
    private $sessionDomain = ".mvcapp2.test";   

    private $sessionSavePath = SESSION_SAVE_PATH;

    private $sessionCipherAlgo = "AES-128-ECB";
    private $sessionCipherKey = "WQAS201VXZP@221D";


    public function __construct()
    {
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
        ini_set('session.save_handler', "files");

        session_name($this->sessionName); 

        session_save_path($this->sessionSavePath);
        session_set_cookie_params(
            $this->sessionMaxLifetime,
            $this->sessionPath,
            $this->sessionDomain,
            $this->sessionSSL,
            $this->sessionHTTPOnly
        );

        session_set_save_handler($this, true);
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        return openssl_decrypt(parent::read($id), $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey);
    }
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        return parent::write($id, openssl_encrypt($data, $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey));
    }
    public function start()
    {
        if ("" === session_id()) {
            return session_start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try as follow:

```
class SessionManager extends SessionHandler
{
    // ...

    public function read($id)
    {
        return openssl_decrypt(parent::read($id), $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey);
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        return parent::write($id, openssl_encrypt($data, $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey));
    }

    // ...
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @method string read(string $id)
 * @method bool write(string $id, string $data)
 */
class SessionManager extends SessionHandler
{
    // ...

    public function read($id)
    {
        return openssl_decrypt(parent::read($id), $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey);
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        return parent::write($id, openssl_encrypt($data, $this->sessionCipherAlgo, $this->sessionCipherKey));
    }

    // ...
}
```